# Content.Binding.ElementName vs DataContext.Binding.ElementName, can anyone explain the subtle differences?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have encountered the following strange behaviour in WPF:

Let's say I have a Window that is implemented in SomeWindow:

```xml
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="SomeWindow">

</Window>
```

In this Class I expose two public properties: one of type SomeModel and one of type ObservableCollection<SomeModel>.
SomeModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and exposes an notifying property SomeProperty.

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<SomeModel> ListOfSomeModel { get; set; }
   public SomeModel InstanceOfSomeModel { get; set; }
}
```

Both are initialized elsewhere, but timely.

Now I can bind these properties to WPF Controls in a couple of different ways:

**Method 1**

I set the DataContext of the Window to itself. The children use this value when none is set on the children itself.

```
public SomeWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = this;
}
```

Next, I do the binding in XAML as follows:

```xml
<Label x:Name="Label1" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfSomeModel[0].SomeProperty}" />
<Label x:Name="Label2" Content="{Binding Path=InstanceOfSomeModel.SomeProperty}" />
```

This works. (As in: both Labels are bound to the Object that is referenced and are updated on mutation of the data).

**Method 2**

There is no default DataContext in SomeWindow, but DataContext is set on the element itself in XAML.

```xml
<Label x:Name="Label1" DataContex="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow}" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfSomeModel[0].SomeProperty}" />
<Label x:Name="Label2" DataContex="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow}" Content="{Binding Path=InstanceOfSomeModel.SomeProperty}" />
```

This also works. So far, so good!

**Method 3**

Now finally, I don't set the DataContext at all, but rather set the Binding.ElementName directly on the Content.

```xml
<Label x:Name="Label1" Content="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow, Path=ListOfSomeModel[0].SomeProperty}" />
```

This **doesn't work**. OK, so maybe I'm not correctly understanding the subtle differences of setting the DataContext vs telling the Binding directly where to look. Maybe this way you can only access the build in properties of the base class. Or maybe....

... BUT WAIT

The other one still works:

```xml
<Label x:Name="Label2" Content="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow, Path=InstanceOfSomeModel.SomeProperty}" />
```

So can anyone explain the technical working of both methods and why in Method 3 the elements of the ObservableCollection are no longer accessible (or at least bindable)? Or am I overlooking something trivial?

**Disclaimers**

- I know it's not safe to access an unordered collection by index.
- I know it's ridiculous to put a reference to a member of a collection in the XAML, as you can never be sure it exists and it's crazy anyway and I should use a ViewModel, etc, etc

It's just like this to demonstrate the observed behaviour.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Method 3 works fine (assuming you initialize your ListOfSomeModel before calling `InitializeComponent` or implement INotifyPropertyChanged on window.

Comment: When in doubt, add a trace to a binding and look at what you see in the output pane in VS: `{Binding Path=ListOfSomeModel[0].SomeProperty, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}`

Comment: I think Evk's right: Order of events. If a binding "fails", it's probably being evaluated before the property has a value. Your properties have no change events, so it never updates. When you bind DataContext, Window.DataContext *does* have a change event btw. Window properties should really be dependency properties -- or better yet, write a viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged properly. Non-notifying properties, viewmodel properties on a window, and `DataContext = this` are all code smells. Don't do any of them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @evk: interesting to read that it works fine at your end. As you point out, must be an initialization thing, altough (in the original code) initialization was done in the Window constructor and works in methods 1 and 2. I'm not sure what you mean by "implement INotifyPropertyChanged on window"

Comment: Well you can just post _full_ minimal example which reproduces your problem, so that we don't need to guess. Such example that everyone can copy and paste into visual studio and immediately see the result.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Didn't know you could put a trace on a binding. Thanks! By the way, the original code did raise a change event and had code to change the properties. Still even after initialization the raised events did not update the UI in method 3.
(And of course: I would never code like this! It's full of code smells as you point out. But I just want to know what's going on here!)

Comment: @evk Full minimal example: yes: I thought this example would reproduce it, as it's the original code, with just the class and property names altered. But I will dig into it tomorrow some more and if necessary, post the original code. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @KarimAyachi I can't diagnose code I've never seen. From years of WPF experience every day at work, if something in the UI doesn't update, I go straight to 1) is the binding's source actually the object I think it is? 2) Is it raising change events correctly? I don't have a step 3 because I've never yet needed one. I've never found any subtleties in this stuff. Never say never, but I'm deeply, deeply skeptical that you've found one.

Comment: Guys, it's solved. Thank you. Indeed ListOfSomeModel was initialized after InitializeComponent. I should have noticed that, but I was thrown off by Methods 1 and 2 working even with initializing the collection after InitializeComponent. Method 3 is working fine if properly initialized. I'm guessing (but have to test it out), that in 3, binding is tried once and fails completely, so even when the event is raised, it's not bound. While in 1 and 2, the DataContext is permanent, so even if initial binding fails, subsequent updates on raised events DO succeed. (so there is a subtle difference :-) )

Comment: Do any of you want to post the answer and get credits for it? Otherwise I will close this question tomorrow.

Comment: Update to previous comment: Step 3 is "Is there a visual tree discontinuity breaking relativesource?". It's Step 4 that there isn't one of.

Answer (score -1):

This is solved with help from the comments above.

The main culprit was (from my original question):

> Both are initialized elsewhere, but timely.

This was false. They were not initialized timely, but after InitializeComponent(). I didn't notice that, because Method 1 and 2 did work.

So the 'subtle difference' I was looking for seems to be:

In the case of methods 1 and 2 a permanent DataContext is set, so even if initial binding of the value fails because the collection is not yet initialized, subsequent updates triggered by the raised PropertyChanged event DO succeed.
In case of method 3, a permanent DataContext is not set and after the initial failed binding, the control is left completely unbound and will not respond to further PropertyChanged events.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: In method 3, the DataContext is irrelevant, because the Binding uses the Window as a source instead of the DataContext.

Comment: That's what I said: "In case of method 3, a permanent DataContext is not set". So indeed it is irrelevant and indeed the Window is the source. But why the downvote? The point here is that when using the Window as a source directly in stead of 'storing' a reference to Window in DataContext, after failed initialization it does not recover from the failed binding, opposed to when keeping the source in DataContext: then it can recover (i.e. update later when the source is sending PropertyChanged events), which was causing the differences in behaviour between the methods.

Comment: I didn’t downvote you. Your second explanation makes more sense than the one in your answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the accusation! :-)